# Google Fit query manually started activites

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I'm trying to query google fit activities that where started by the user going into google fit pressing + -> start activity -> start, as opposed to the usually passively tracked activity, I originally thought this was what the sessions api was for but I think that may be for something else.

```
private SessionReadRequest querySessionData() {
    // Set a start and end time for our query, using a start time of 4 week before this moment.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -4);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    // Build a session read request
    return new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            //.setSessionName()
            .build();
}
```

I was then hoping to get activity data historically but then when I got no results back from the query I presumed I was using the wrong api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so eventually I worked out that I can achieve what I wanted using the history api and the key is to BUCKET BY SESSION, so first create the request like this:

```
private DataReadRequest querySessionData() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    //query 30 days in the past
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, - 30);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();


    return new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_SPEED, DataType.AGGREGATE_SPEED_SUMMARY)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)

            .bucketBySession(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
}
```

Then to use that request use the history api like this:

```
final DataReadRequest readRequest = querySessionData();
Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
            //do your stuff!!
        }
     });
 }
```